# Adding offset to GeoJSON layer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, linestring

Using the example GeoJSON tutorial code at [leafletjs.com](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html).
Change the `myLines` variable so that the two lines overlap, but run in opposite directions as follows:

```
var myLines = [{
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[-100, 40], [-105, 45], [-110, 55]]
}, {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [[-110, 55], [-105, 45], [-100, 40]]
}];
```

This overlapping is a common situation with `lineString` shapes, especially roads.  In QGIS/ArcMap, one can apply an Offset = X to the layer such that a positive offset shifts each line feature X (pixels, map units) to the right, in the direction of travel (starting coordinate to ending coordinate), and a negative offset shifts the line to the left, in the direction of travel.

There does not appear to be an option in Leaflet which would allow one to apply a similar offset in the `style` to these lines so that they are not shown overlapping.  Markers seem to have this option, but not lines.  I was hoping the following code would work, but it doesn't since "offset" is not a valid option.

```
var myStyle = {
    "color": "#ff7800",
    "weight": 5,
    "opacity": 0.65,
    "offset": 1.5
};

L.geoJson(myLines, {
    style: myStyle
}).addTo(map);
```

Does this option exist or is it perhaps called something else?

Comment: One way of achieving this could be to make a Javascript function that takes in `myLines` and then returns a `geojson` object with the coordinates offset. You would need to loop through the coordinates and and the offset to the values.

Comment: @djq Yes, but how to implement such a thing? The offset would depend on the zoom level, the angle between coordinates and the bearing of the segments between coordinates, no?

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset) seems to hold most of the solution. However it applies to polyline and not specifically GeojJSON. Has anyone solved the problem above? If not, any suggestions on how to combine the PolylineOffset code efficiently? Matt

Comment: Created [Leaflet PR #4727](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4727) to add [Leaflet Polyline Offset](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineOffset) plugin to the list of Leaflet plugins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Romain D on it1me.com](http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=33297951&ttl=Adding%20an%20animated%20arrow%20on%20an%20offset%20Leaflet%20polyline), it can be done with the Leaflet.PolylineOffset as referenced in the comments by MattPil29 above.

I have adapted it for the data in your example. I turned off your original line by changing opacity to 0 in myStyle. There is probably a more elegant way to not add it.

The other key is flipping the x,y coordinate to make L.Polyline happy.

See a fiddle here, [Leaflet Offset geojson](https://jsfiddle.net/tlohnes/rrq81rw9/)

Main code

```js
var myLines = [{
  "type": "LineString",
  "coordinates": [[-100, 40], [-105, 45], [-110, 55]]
}, {
  "type": "LineString",
  "coordinates": [[-110, 55], [-105, 45], [-100, 40]]
}];

var myStyle = {
  "color": "#ff7800",
  "weight": 5,
  "opacity": 0,
  "offset": 1.5
};

L.geoJson(myLines, {
  style: myStyle,
  onEachFeature: function(feature){
    var coords = feature.coordinates;
    var lengthOfCoords = feature.coordinates.length;

    //reverse x, y order for L.polyline
    for (i=0;i<lengthOfCoords;i++)
      {
      // swap x and y, save x in var holdLon then drop back into second position
        holdLon = coords[i][0];
        coords[i][0] = coords[i][1];
        coords[i][1] = holdLon;
     }

    var offset = L.polyline(coords, {offset: 5, color: 'black'}).addTo(map);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

edit: If you don't want the original lines at all just remove the

```js
.addTo(map)
```

in the last line, leave it as

```js
)};
```

Then you can remove

```js
style: myStyle,
```

Comment: Took the liberty to simplify the code in your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rrq81rw9/23/ so that it is easier to see the app code, rather than having to scroll down after the plugin code.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea how to call the plugin. Much better your way.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the original line geometry rather than adding a new one?

Comment: @underdark altering the above code you could swap the coordinates from `lon, lat` to `lat, lon` and create two separate L.polyline features, bypassing the `L.geoJson` creation step: https://jsfiddle.net/clhenrick/py2suokw/3/

Comment: @clhenrick Thanks but I had some events bound to the GeoJson layer features and those all break with these approaches ... but maybe there is no way around that

Comment: @underdark I think it is certainly possible to get the coordinates from the leaflet offset poly line code and reassign them to the geojson and add that to the map. Why do you prefer doing it that way?

Comment: @underdark if you'd like to attach event listeners you could store the `L.polyline` layers in a [`L.featureGroup`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup). This would allow you to listen for events. That being said it is much easier to attach event listeners to an `L.geoJson` layer via passing the `onEachFeature` option. When I tried using the plug in above and then calling `toGeoJSON()` on the `L.polyline` layers the offset didn't seem to persist. If it did persist, I would run the offset on the polylines, convert them to GeoJSON, then add them to a `L.geoJson` layer. But alas...

Comment: @underdark I started toying with getting the coordinates from the leaflet offset polyline code in order to replace the geojson coordinates. On vacation so probably won't have a chance to delve deeper until next week.